# Scheme - Working with List of Lists

Tags: scheme, racket

Currently for an assignment I'm working on a scheme problem where we are representing a graph using scheme lists. The first variation we are using is an edge-list graph represented as

```
'((x y) (y z) (x z))
```

The second variation of the graph we are using is being called an x-graph represented as

```
((x (y z)) (y (z)) (z ()))
```

Our task is the write two procedures to convert from each form to the other and I'm at a loss at how to tackle this problem. I understand the general idea of the formula, grabbing a node and constructing a list or deconstructing based on the edges but I don't see how the list is supposed to be built as you go along. Looking for some guidance not an answer.

I'll post the question here just for further clarification if I did not describe it well enough.

Consider two techniques for representing a graph as Scheme lists. We can represent a directed graph as a list of edges. We call this representation an el-graph (i.e. edge-list graph). An edge is itself a list of length two such that the first element is a symbol denoting the source of the edge and the second element is a symbol denoting the target of the edge. Note that an edge is a list (not just a pair). For example, the following is a graph: '((x y) (y z) (x z)). We can also represent a graph similar to an adjacency matrix. We call this representation an x-graph (i.e. matrix-graph). In this case, a graph is a list of adjacencies where an adjacency is a list of length two such that the first element is a node (a symbol) and the second element is a list of the targets of that node. For example, the following is a graph: '((x (y z)) (y (z)) (z ())).

```
Write function (el-graph->x-graph g), that accepts an el-graph g and returns an x-graph of g.
Write function (x-graph->el-graph g), that accepts an x-graph g and returns an el-graph of g.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippets below are actual answers, but I did my best to actually explain what's being done so you can disregard the code and write your own thing, if you want to.

Converting from the x-graph to the edge-list graph is straightforward. Consider your example: `((x (y z)) (y (z)) (z ()))`. When you go into the first sublist, you want to generate `((x y) (x z))`; when you go into the second sublist, you want to generate `((y z))`; and when you go into the third sublist, you want to generate `()`. You then use `append-map` to flat-map all those results into a single list.

```
(define (x-graph->el-graph g)
  (append-map (lambda (sublist)
                (define from-node (car sublist))
                (define to-nodes (cadr sublist))
                (map (lambda (to-node)
                       (list from-node to-node))
                     to-nodes))
              g))
```

---

Going from edge-list graph to x-graph is probably most easily done using `group-by` to group the edges by the from-node, then gathering up the to-nodes in each group. However, that will not give you the empty `z` association (I'll leave that as an exercise for you).

```
(define (el-graph->x-graph g)
  (map (lambda (group)
         (list (caar group) (map cadr group)))
       (group-by car g eq?)))
```

Comment: Would you be able to just explain a little more how group-by works, we haven't learned about it yet so just curious how it works.

Comment: `group-by` is defined here: https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/v6.12/racket/collects/racket/list.rkt#L772

Basically, it: 1. builds a hash, keyed by the result of the keying function, with the value being a list of values with the same key; 2. returns the values of that hash, ordered by the location of first appearance in the original list.